# Angular http.post by ID to update current record

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a successful HTTPGET, HTTPDELETE, HTTPPUT(add new record), and HTTPPOST(UPDATE) that works well in postman. I have also implemented the get, delete and put into my angular model, but can't seem to wrap my head around the httppost. I have a html page with fields, fields and more fields. Inputs, selects and dates.

My working put angular controller look like below:

```
vm.addComplaint = function () {
        vm.errorMessage = "";
        vm.isBusy = true;

        $http.put(baseURL + "api/comp", vm.newComplaint)
        .then(function (response) {
            vm.complaints.push(response.data);

            vm.newComplaint = {};
        }
        , function (error) {
            //error
            vm.errorMessage = "Failed to save new trip" + error;
        })
        .finally(function () {
            vm.isBusy = false;
        })
    };
```

**Question**
How do I write my angular controller to perform a post like it does in postman and do I need to pass in the fields for it to work?

```
$http.post(baseURL+ "api/comp/" + Id).success(function(data){
 alert("Updated Successfully!")
//how do  save data here
}).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occurred while Saving Customer! " + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your url is correct? Rather than the following:

```
$http.post(baseURL+ "api/comp" + Id)
```

I expect to see any of the following:

```
$http.post(baseURL+ "api/comp/" + Id)
$http.post(baseURL+ "api/comp", Id)
$http.post(baseURL+ "api/comp", someObjectToPostWhichIncludesAnId)
```

**Update**
Your `post` code will most likely look just like your `put` code. I expect to see something like this:

```
$http.post(baseURL+ "api/comp", comp)
    .then(function(response) {
        // do something to handle a successful call
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // handle the error
    });
```

Comment: I corrected the url, the reason why I am asking how I write it is because I am not sure how to write controller so that it is passing the someObjectToPostWhichIncludesAnId, in my case it would probably be $http.post(baseURL+ "api/comp/", comps), but still I am unsure of how to complete the code. Thanks for the corrections.